Python Multiprocessing Self-updating Object
I'm trying to write a display for cardinal directions. I've got an interface that runs at a high refresh rate, and a hardware device that only updates a few times a second.
I need to be able to get the latest reported values from the hardware to the display every time the display updates.
My current approach is to try multiprocessing. I have a process that gets the values and updates the object, via shared-state pipes, with those values, and I have a process that takes the values from the object and updates the display.
Unfortunately, it seems to be blocking somewhere, and the display is locked to the hardware update speed.
class AccMag():
    # Init manually to ensure access to and for internal functions
    def init(self):
        # This defines the hardware access
        self.i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
        self.mag = adafruit_lis2mdl.LIS2MDL(self.i2c)
        self.accel = adafruit_lsm303_accel.LSM303_Accel(self.i2c)

        # Output values (mag#) and pipes to the other process
        self.magx = 0
        self.pipex = multiprocessing.Value('d', 0.0)
        self.magy = 0
        self.pipey = multiprocessing.Value('d', 0.0)
        self.magz = 0
        self.pipez = multiprocessing.Value('d', 0.0)

        # The process, named thread.  Yes, my cat is named Rex.
        self.thread = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.threadmagdate, args=(self.pipex, self.pipey, self.pipez))
        self.thread.start()

        # A counter I use to see how often the process has run.
        # Comparing this counter to a similar one in the display is how I know it's blocking.
        self.tc = 0

    # The function that starts the process to update the values
    def magdate(self):
        # Check the current process is done
        self.thread.join(timeout=0)
        if self.thread.is_alive() == False:
            # Pull out previous values
            self.magx = self.pipex.value
            self.magy = self.pipey.value
            self.magz = self.pipez.value
            self.tc += 1
            # Start a new process
            self.thread = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.threadmagdate, args=(self.pipex, self.pipey, self.pipez))
            self.thread.start()

    # Get the data from the hardware into the pipe
    def threadmagdate(self, magx, magy, magz,):
        magx.value = int(self.mag.magnetic[1])
        magy.value = int(self.mag.magnetic[0])
        magz.value = int(self.mag.magnetic[2])

The display can then call magdate() and grab the values from the mag# values.
I'm missing something obvious, I can smell it, but I've got no idea why it's locking.

You probably don’t need multiprocessing to parallelize I/O; threads should suffice, and will be simpler as you can directly use shared variables. (You can use shared memory with multiprocessing, but it’s somewhat more complex)

Thanks for the suggestion, I modified the code to use threads instead of processes, but found that it started not returning any values at all. I'm going to be switching to Rust for this project, but will gladly keep trying any more suggestions in-case it helps anyone else in the future, and will explore making sure to extract the values cleanly.

Something like this should work with threads:
class AccMag:
    # Init manually to ensure access to and for internal functions
    def __init__(self):
        # This defines the hardware access
        self.i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
        self.mag = adafruit_lis2mdl.LIS2MDL(self.i2c)
        self.accel = adafruit_lsm303_accel.LSM303_Accel(self.i2c)

        self.mag_data = (0, 0, 0)
        self.update_count = 0

        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self._mag_thread, daemon=True)
        self.thread.start()

    # Get the data from the hardware into the pipe
    def _mag_thread(self):
        while True:
            mag = tuple(map(int, self.mag.magnetic))
            self.mag_data = mag
            self.update_count += 1

There's no need to manually call magdata with this implementation: just grab the x, y, z values from .mag_data directly.
In your main display application, copy a reference to the mag_data tuple in a local variable (e.g. cur_data = accmag.mag_data; x = cur_data[0]) rather than accessing fields directly (e.g. x = accmag.mag_data[0]) in order to avoid racing with the update thread and seeing partial results.
However, I suspect your blocking issue lies elsewhere, given that the other answer should exhibit zero blocking as well and yet seems to block for you.

Thanks for this feedback, this has indeed proven to me that my issue lies elsewhere, and that the AccMag class being called by the HUD's main method was where the delay arose. The AccMag's update_count far exceeded the main method's.

self.thread.join(timeout=0) seems to be a pointless line of code since join() is typically used to wait for a period of time for a process to finish, but in this case it doesn't actually wait at all.
Based on your code, I don't see anything that could be blocking, but on some platforms, starting a new process can take a while (sometimes more than 1s) depending on the process start method.
Given that magdate() is likely to start a new process every time it's called, I suspect this is where the 'blocking' happens.
So instead of starting a new process every time in magdate(), I'd suggest to use a Queue object instead.
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process, Event

class AccMag():
    # Init manually to ensure access to and for internal functions
    def init(self):
        # This defines the hardware access
        self.i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
        self.mag = adafruit_lis2mdl.LIS2MDL(self.i2c)
        self.accel = adafruit_lsm303_accel.LSM303_Accel(self.i2c)

        # Set up queue and a termination event
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.terminate_event = Event()

        # The process, named thread.  Yes, my cat is named Rex.
        self.thread = Process(target=self.threadmagdate, args=(self.queue, self.terminate_event))
        self.thread.start()

        # A counter I use to see how often the process has run.
        # Comparing this counter to a similar one in the display is how I know it's blocking.
        self.tc = 0

    def stop(self):
        self.terminate_event.set()  ## trigger termination event
        self.thread.join()  ## wait for process to terminate

    # The function that starts the process to update the values
    def magdate(self):
        # Check if new value is available
        if not self.queue.empty():
            x, y, z = self.queue.get()

            # Pull out new values
            self.magx = int(x)
            self.magy = int(y)
            self.magz = int(z)

            self.tc += 1

    # Get the data from the hardware into the pipe
    def threadmagdate(self, queue, terminate_event):
        while not terminate_event.is_set():  ## check if it's time to stop reading values
            queue.put(self.mag.magnetic)  ## insert new reading into queue


After implementing the suggested code, I'm still finding that the frame-rate is in step with the magnetometer's output speed. It's very possible that self.mag.magnetic is an object that runs its own function when values are requested, pulling the data back into the main process.
I'm going to be switching to Rust for this project, but will gladly keep trying any more suggestions in-case it helps anyone else in the future, and will explore making sure to extract the values cleanly in the second process.

@Sarazil checking the implementation of the LIS2MDL class, the returned magnetic value is a plain tuple. Therefore there should not be any magic behaviour there. I suspect your bug lies elsewhere.
